# Calculating averages in another method C++

Tags: c++, average

I separated the average method from main, the two students in main both call the method but I am not quite sure as to how to calculate the average by doing it this way, any ideas?

Average does two things.  It computes the average of the student’s scores, places the integer average in the final element thus replacing the negative number it then returns the number of actual test scores it found in the array.  The sentinel in the array is a negative number.

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double average( int array[]); // function declaration (prototype)

int main()
{
    int lazlo[] = {90, 80, 85, 75, 65, -10};
    int pietra[] = { 100, 89, 83, 96, 98, 72, 78, -1};
    int num;

    num = average( lazlo );
    cout << "lazlo took " << num << "tests. Average: " << lazlo[ num ] << endl;

    num = average( pietra );
    cout << "pietra took " << num << "test. Average: " << pietra[ num ] << endl;

}

double average( int array[])
{
  // Average code

}
```

Comment: Your `average` function has no idea how many items there are in the array.  Does that help you figure out what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Now that we finally know the true assignment:

> "Average does two things. It computes the average of the student’s scores, places the integer average in the final element thus replacing the negative number it then returns the number of actual test scores it found in the array. The sentinel in the array is a negative number"

```
double average( int array[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int Total = 0;
    while (array[i] >= 0)       //Keep adding to total and increase i until negative value found. 
        Total += array[i++];

    array[i] = Total / i; 
    return i;                   //Weird to return a double for this, but if that is the assignment...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to pass a C-style array as the sole argument to the `average()` function, you must use templates to deduce its size:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
size_t count(int (&array)[N])
{
    return N;
}

template <size_t N>
double average(int (&array)[N])
{
    return std::accumulate(array, array + N, 0.0) / N;
}

int main()
{
    int lazlo[] = {90, 80, 85, 75, 65, -10};

    double num = average( lazlo );
    cout << "lazlo took " << count(lazlo) << " tests. Average: " << average(lazlo) << endl;
}
```

Of course, since this is C++, you might be better off using `std::vector` or `std::array` to store the scores, in which case you could do this:

```
double average(const std::vector<int>& array)
{
    return std::accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 0.0) / array.size();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I am only able to edit the average method and prototype, not the entire program @JohnZwinck

Comment: @HoodCoolege: No problem--you can plug my first version of `average` into your existing program.  It's called exactly the same way.